# What is the use of requireBinding?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I am relatively new to Guice and trying to understand the usage of requireBinding and when/why to use it.

As per my understanding, while creating an injector Guice goes through the code of configure() method of all the modules and builds a dependency graph.

If Guice builds the dependency graph in itself then why does a module need to add a requireBinding? As long as I could understand the usage of requireBinding is to add an explicit dependency on a class which guice's dependency graph seems to be doing anyway.

I would like to understand that when should we use requireBinding and what is the impact of not using it in a module.

I have read Guice's official documentation and search on all the existing questions on Stackoverflow/any other blog but couldn't find a satisfying answer to the above question.

**Adding to the original question.**

Looking at the Source code of the AbstractModule the implementation looks like

```
protected void requireBinding(Key<?> key) {
    this.binder().getProvider(key);
}

protected void requireBinding(Class<?> type) {
    this.binder().getProvider(type);
}
```

Which you would assume will not have any side effect as it's a "get" call.
But on the other hand looking it the binder itself it adds some element to a list of elements of type **ProviderLookup**

```
public <T> Provider<T> getProvider(Dependency<T> dependency) {
        ProviderLookup<T> element = new ProviderLookup(this.getElementSource(), dependency);
        this.elements.add(element);
        return element.getProvider();
    }
```

Comment: FWIW we (internally) typically discourage `requireBinding()`. In general `requireBinding()` introduces a "requirement" that isn't actually there (otherwise you'd get a binding error without needing it), which makes the module more brittle than strictly necessary. I think it would be (slightly) more useful if it took a `String` argument so you could provide a more helpful error message than what you get by default, but as-is it's no better than *actually* requiring the binding by depending on it.

Answer (score 4):

I've always though of requireBinding() as a contract for the Module.

You are correct that the graph would eventually fail when you call `#get()` or tried to inject an object that depends on the binding. However, I believe requireBinding will cause a failure when the Injector is created vs when the object is created (via the injector). When I was at Google, it functioned more as a contract, less as something with consequential behavior.